# How do I randomly return one of two other elements out of a total of three elements in a list? Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have three elements in a list. I have selected one of these elements based on my condition and now I need to randomly return one of the other two elements left in the list. I must do this without changing the list or the position of the elements. Java.

```
    else if(selectedElement == list.indexOf("Element1")) {
        alternativeElement = random.nextInt(list.size());
    }
    return alternativeElement;
```

This is what I had so far but it is not working.

Comment: Conceptually and straight off the top my head.  Generate a random number between `0` and the list `size` (`0-2` for three elements), if the value is `>=` the `selectedElement`, add `1` to it, unless the selected index is the last element, then subtract `1`

Comment: Monty Hall simulation?

Comment: `int alternativeElement = selectedElement; while (alternativeElement == selectedElement) {alternativeElement = random.nextInt(list.size()); } return alternativeElement;` That assumes `list` does, in fact, have more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 20 items in the list. Randomly, you selected 15 before.

Think about the think you are 'modelling'. Technically, you're modelling marbles in a bag, and one was taken out. However, one of the rules of your homework exercise is that you can't modify the list, so the obvious thing to do (which is to **actually** remove the 15th marble from your bag, i.e. remove the 15th element from your list by executing `list.remove(14)`), is disallowed.

Still, that doesn't change what's actually happening.

So, if you are to emulate drawing another marble out of that bag, how many possible marbles are available to choose? **19**.

So, you run `rnd.nextInt(19)` to get a random number between 0 and 18 inclusive (a total of 19 different options).

The thing is, if for example that random number says 'take the 17th marble', we're supposed to *skip past* the 15th, which is supposed to not be there.

That's easy enough!

```
int nextMarbleIdx = rnd.nextInt(19);
int actualIndexInList = nextMarbleIdx >= 14 ? nextMarbleIdx + 1 : nextMarbleIdx;
```

Note that this works great because it's easy to write a check to skip past that single marble that was drawn the first time. This becomes a very unwieldy algorithm if you want to draw, say, 15 marbles randomly out of a 20 marble bag without replacement.

If *that* is the job, this isn't going to work. You need a different way of thinking.

### Shuffle

Shuffle the marbles once, then just draw the marbles off the top. It's just like a deck of cards: If you have a pack of cards and someone asks you to 'draw me 25 cards from random places in the deck, without putting any drawn card back into the deck', then that is statistically 100% equivalent to: "Please shuffle the deck properly. Then give me the top 25 cards". It's 25 completely random unique cards either way. Hence, all you need to do to provide for the question: "I have a bag of Y marbles. Draw me X of them at random without replacement" is to take Y, shuffle Y, and then just return off the top. No need to involve any sort of randomness in any way other than that initial shuffle. This is very easy to do in java with lists:

```
int MAX_MARBLES = 100;
int MARBLES_TO_DRAW = 20;
var marbles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_MARBLES; i++) marbles.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(marbles); // the magic happens here
for (int i = 0; i < MARBLES_TO_DRAW; i++) {
  // Just draw the last marble out of the bag.
  System.out.println("Your marble: " + marbles.remove(marbles.size() - 1));
}
```

Ah, but, this modifies the list, you say.

No worries. You can make copies, you know. Just make a copy of your input (so that you can shuffle the copy, leaving the original untouched).

### Bizarre non-issues

1. Someone tells you: This isn't okay because making a copy is expensive. No, it isn't; even if the things in the bag are cruise ships, in java all objects are stored by reference - that's a bag with the addresses where the cruise ships are harboured that you're shuffling, not a bag full with 100 cruise ships. That would indeed be highly unwieldy and inefficient, but, fortunately, not how java works.
2. That's not properly random. Incorrect - `Collections.shuffle()` uses a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) - plenty of papers and code around showing how that properly shuffles. It's as random as can be: Your odds at guessing the next item in the shuffled list is as good as even chance even if you know of the marbles taken out immediately before you have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
alternativeElement = random.nextBoolean() ? 0 : 2;
if (alternativeElement == selectedElement) {
    alternativeElement = 1;
}
```